# How to download On Demand frameworks / SDKs?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone

I was doing some research into on demand resource download for apps, i can see that on iOS sprite kits for games and assets can be downloaded on demand, i was wondering if there is any way to download framework for normal apps on native platform. entire SDKs or framework to be downloaded if necessary, just to reduce the size of the app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift is a statically compiled language so you cannot download new frameworks.  To the extent that you build scripting into your app I suppose you can change some features.  The downloads you are referring to are part of Apple's app thinning frameworks which are meant for data, since usually your data is much larger than your code.

See the apple docs:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/reducing_your_app_s_size

Comment: i understand the entire app thinning process, i was wondering if this is possible, i mean on a hybrid platform i suppose scripts can be downloaded and executed, i guess this is one of the drawbacks if i understand the concept correctly, its not just reducing app size, if i want to expose certain features to certain user groups, is there any way to download certain  SDK/framework itself instead of bundling the entire thing in the app and handle it in my code. that was my question, i guess its not possible on a native platform.

Comment: Also i just found out that android has something called play feature delivery, i mean even android is built using java technically a compiled language and they have proposed this on demand feature download.